# Generate and validate OWIN user tokens across domains

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, owin

I would like to know whether it's possible to validate ASP.NET Identity user tokens on website 1, generated on website 2.

In my case, both websites actually use the same `UserManager`, which is defined in an assembly that both sites use. `Startup.Auth.cs` is identitical for the two sites. However, a token generated on the first site fails to validate on the other one.

Code used on first website to generate token:

```
string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var manager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
string token = await manager.GenerateUserTokenAsync("SomePurpose", userId);
```

Then passed as query parameters to the other website:

```
var manager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

if (await manager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(userId, "SomePurpose", token)) 
{
    // Do something
}
```

Validation always fails in this scenario. If I validate the token on the same site where it was generated, it passes.

Here's how the token provider is assigned in `ApplicationUserManager` (`options.DataProtectionProvider` is of type `CallDataProtectionProvider` at runtime):

```
var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;

if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
{
    manager.UserTokenProvider =
        new DataProtectorTokenProvider<UserProfile>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("SomeName"));
}
```

Is this behavior intentional or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you validate the token on the same site, do you validate it in same action where it was generated?

Comment: @tmg Same action or different action, both work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out token generation and verification use the machine key. To generate/verify, the websites need to have the same `machineKey` configured.